# ValueError: time data 'End Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert date to time stamp

I am reading data from a csv and its content

```
CID,End Date,License Key 
bcc1,3/11/2022,abc
```

My main function looks like this

```
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as file:
        csvfile= csv.reader(file,delimiter=",")
        for row in csvfile:
            CID = row[0]
            DATE = str(row[1])
            END_DATE = datetime.datetime.strptime(DATE,"%m/%d/%Y").timetuple()
            # END_DATE= datetime.datetime(int(END_DATE)).strftime('%s')
            EVAL_SKU_LIST = row[2]
            print CID
            print (DATE)
            print EVAL_SKU_LIST
```

I am getting an error saying

> ValueError: time data 'End Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Comment: What is the value of DATE?

Comment: 3/11/2022 as in the CSV mentioned above

Comment: skip the first row. the code is trying to interpret header row values?

Comment: Yes that is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CID,End Date,License Key 
> bcc1,3/11/2022,abc
> ```

> ValueError: time data **'End Date'** does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

It's all there in the error message. You are passing the string `'End Date'` to `strptime`, not `'3/11/2022'`.

You need to skip the first row of the CSV file which contains the headers.

For example, like this:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
headers = next(csvfile)  # read one row
for row in csvfile:      # iterate over all subsequent rows
    # ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate headings with content?